# How can i make a button hover (animation) without making it invisible as it hovers in visibility

Tags: java, android

So apparently My button blinks and disappears and this is not what i want. What i wish to have is my button hover around on click and not onclick(blink but in visible motion). I will appreciate any help. I dont want it to be invisible. I would like it to hover while visible

```
final Animation animationPlay = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); 
      animationPlay.setDuration(600)
```

Say this is my button [image]

Comment: Use a [state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground).

Comment: @karaokyo thank you very much, That has worked for me :)